# Copy 2D array using memcpy?

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

So I want to copy the contents of a 2D array to another array of the exact same type. Here is how the array is created:

```
 GridUnit** newGrid;
 newGrid = new GridUnit*[width];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        newGrid[i] = new GridUnit[height];
```

GridUnit is size 16 (4 floats). So that's all initialised fine, no problems with using it as it is after I have ran the for loops to actually fill the values with some data. Now what I want to do is copy the contents of another array into this one (without for loops if possible). This is what I have been trying to do so far:

```
 memcpy(&newGrid, &grid, height * width * 16);
```

'grid' is identical to 'newGrid' in terms of its size and type. However, this does not work. I know the memcpy is possibly not correct, but having tried multiple different setups using this, I don't know what's going wrong with it anymore, so any help would be welcome!

Comment: Oh gosh. Just use vectors please, and it will *just work*. `vec1 = vec2;`

Comment: Yeah it would make my life so much easier, it just happens that I didn't decide to use arrays like that and now they're being used all over the code base.

Comment: I would seriously consider rewriting it. Vectors have so many advantages, such as bounds checking on good debug compilers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you actually had a 2-D array, that `memcpy` call would work.  But you don't, you have `width` separate discontiguous 1-D arrays, collected in an array of pointers.

It is possible to dynamically allocate a contiguous block where row and column count both vary at runtime, and preserve the two-subscript access.  You'll have to change the allocation code as follows:

```
GridUnit** newGrid;
newGrid = new GridUnit*[width];
newGrid[0] = new GridUnit[width * height];
for (int i = 1; i < width; i++)
    newGrid[i] = newGrid[i-1] + height;
```

Deallocation becomes simpler:

```
delete[] newGrid[0];
delete[] newGrid;
```

There's no `delete[]` for `newGrid[i]` with `i > 0` because they don't have their own blocks, they just point into the single large block.  Because everything is contiguous, you can think of `newGrid[0]` either as a pointer to the first row (`height` elements), or the entire 2-D array (`width * height` elements).

And you can then access all the data as a single contiguous block:

```
memcpy(newGrid[0], oldGrid[0], height * width * sizeof newGrid[0][0]);
```

---

Of course, one shouldn't use raw pointers for memory ownership.  A smart pointer will ensure the memory is properly deleted even with exceptional flow control.  It would look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<GridUnit[]> newData;
std::unique_ptr<GridUnit*[]> newGrid;
// before C++14 use // newData.reset(new GridUnit[width * height]);
newData = std::make_unique<GridUnit[]>(width * height);
// before C++14 use // newGrid.reset(new GridUnit*[width]);
newGrid = std::make_unique<GridUnit*[]>(width);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    newGrid[i] = &newData[i * height];
```

Comment: Oh of course, can't believe I didn't realise that. Makes a lot of sense why it wasn't working now. However, I don't see a resolution short of using for loops if I still want to use this array setup?

Comment: If height is a constant, it can be done, i.e getting a 2D array with new. But is it?

Comment: @KieronH See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new for more information

Comment: @KieronH: I edited in an approach that I think you might find useful.

Comment: Wow, that's ingenious!

Comment: This is great. Better yet if you wrap around a `Matrix` class or get a library that does.