# cpp 3d dynamic creation of 3d arrays consisting of one single memory block

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d

I have to implement a simulation on a 3D Ising lattice represented by ones and minus ones on a 3D it would be very useful if the size could be determined at runtime (for more flexibility).
As there are many accesses to the entries the memory allocation should be as local as possible.
If found something  for a 2D array:
[Copy 2D array using memcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375797/copy-2d-array-using-memcpy/29375830) :

```
GridUnit** newGrid;
newGrid = new GridUnit*[width];
newGrid[0] = new GridUnit[width * height];
for (int i = 1; i < width; i++)
    newGrid[i] = newGrid[i-1] + height;
```

Deallocation becomes simpler:

```
delete[] newGrid[0];
delete[] newGrid;
```

and my rating is too low to comment or reply to the post.
I have basically two questions about the code:
1.why is the grid defined as pointers to arrays of
`length = width`
and the the iteration takes place over an index going up to width shifting the address by height? isn't that messing up the row and column index?
2.Should I then declare an array of `length=width` with pointers to arrays of `length=height*depth`which would result in the following code:

```
int*** new3dGrid(int width, int height, int depth){
  int*** newGrid;
  newGrid = new int**[height*depth];
  newGrid[0][0] = new int[width * height * depth];
  for (int i = 1; i < width; i++){
    newGrid[i] = newGrid[i-1] + height*depth;
    for (int j=1;j<height;j++){
      newGrid[i][j]=newGrid[i][j-1]+depth;
    }
  }
  return newGrid;
}
```

Comment: The 3-D case is covered in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582795/103167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: I **STRONGLY** suggest you to use, when possible, standard C++ containers; in 2D case (caution: not tested)

```
std::vector<std::vector<GridUnit> >  gu2d (width, std::vector<GridUnit>(height));
```

I strongly suggest this especially if isn't absolutely clear the example that you mention.

Consider if you access at position `i`, `j`

```
gu2d[i][j] = GridUnit();
```

where, by mistake, `j` value is `height`; without realizing it, you modify `gu2d[i+1][0]`. If `gu2d` is a vector of vectors, with `gu2d.at(i).at(j)` you obtain bound checking and a nice exception.

> 1. why is the grid defined as pointers to arrays of length = width and the iteration takes place over an index going up to width shifting the address by height?

You can see a 2D matrix as an array of `width` rows of cells where each row is of `height` cells.

So the first pointer (`newGrid`) has lenght `width` because it references `width` rows.

Every row has length `height`, so the `width` values referenced by `newGrid` are separated (shifted) by a space of `height` (in pointer metric).

I think you can be clearer if you read the first answer to this question

[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

> 2. Should I then declare an array of length=width with pointers to arrays of length=height*depth which would result in the following code

I'm not an English native speaker but it seems to me that you have chosen an unhappy order of names. I suppose you should use `depth` **before** `width`.

But, using your actual names (`width` is the dimension of the first index, `height` of the second, `depth` of the third)...

Exactly.

Your code should change

```
newGrid = new int**[height*depth];
```

width

```
newGrid = new int**[width];
```

In the 3D case, you can see `newGrid` as (with your choose one names) an array of `width` 2D matrix where the 2D matrix are array of `height` rows of `depth` cells. So every 2D matrix is of size `heigth * depth`.

Caution: remember to delete with

```
delete newGrid[0][0];
delete newGrid;
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

**--- EDIT ---**

Sorry: I haven't seen a point that is important about your hypotesis of `new3dGrid`: you should allocate **three** pointers, not two: `newGrid`, as `int***`, for size `width`; `newGrid[0]`, as `int**` for size `width * height`; `newGrid[0][0]`, as `int*`, for size `width * height * depth`. The three types of pointers need different allocated area.

I propose the different template version (caution: not tested) [corrected by Ben Voigt; thanks!]

```
template <typename T>
T*** new3dGrid (unsigned height, unsigned width, unsigned depth)
 {
   T*** newGrid;

   newGrid       = new T**[width];
   newGrid[0]    = new T*[width * height];
   newGrid[0][0] = new T[width * height * depth];

   for ( unsigned i = 0U ; i < width ; ++i )
    {
      if ( i > 0U )
       {
         newGrid[i]    = newGrid[i-1U]    + height;
         newGrid[i][0] = newGrid[i-1U][0] + height * depth;
       }

      for ( unsigned j = 1U ; i < height ; ++j )
         newGrid[i][j] = newGrid[i][j-1U] + depth;
    }

   return newGrid;
 }
```

and you should delete three pointers

```
delete newGrid[0][0];
delete newGrid[0];
delete newGrid;
```

Sorry.

Comment: This line is a mistake: `newGrid[i] = newGrid[i-1U] + height * depth;`, please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582795/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt - D'oh! You're right! I've mixed the code for two different levels and forgotten to initialize at level zero. Thanks. Please, can you verify if I've correctly modified my code (that is: if I've correctly copied your code)?

Comment: you've a `for` when you meant `if`, otherwise it looks ok