# Assigning memory in C++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to learn how to assign memory in C++. I followed this answer to allocating 2-D arrays: [Copy 2D array using memcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375797/copy-2d-array-using-memcpy/29375830#29375830)

However, when I attempt to combine this and copying memory using `std::copy` I get a corruption.

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{

  private:

    int nrows;
    int mcols;
    double **entry;


  public:

  Matrix(int n, int m);

  ~Matrix();

  Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& mat_in);

};

Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m)
{
  nrows = n;
  mcols = m;

  std::cout << "Using regular constructor" << std::endl;

  entry    = new double*[nrows];
  entry[0] = new double[nrows * mcols];
  for(int i=1;i<nrows;i++)
    entry[i] = entry[i-1] + mcols;

  for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<mcols;j++)
      entry[i][j] = 0.0;
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
  delete[] entry[0];
  delete[] entry;
}



Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& mat_in)
{
  std::cout << "using deep copy constructor" << std::endl;

  if(this == &mat_in)
    return *this;

  double **p = new double*[mat_in.nrows];
  p[0] = new double[mat_in.nrows * mat_in.mcols];

  std::copy(mat_in.entry, mat_in.entry + (mat_in.nrows * mat_in.mcols), p);

  delete[] this -> entry;

  entry = p;
  nrows = mat_in.nrows;
  mcols = mat_in.mcols;

  return *this;
}
int main()

{
  Matrix A(3,3);

  Matrix B(3,3);

  B = A;

  return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is that I don't fully understand what is happening when I free the memory and I am freeing it twice.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need an array of pointers ("2D array")? Why will a single array of `double`s (of size width × height) not suffice? It would certainly be a _lot_ simpler and then you probably wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Consider learning from a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) instead.

Comment: Consider using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of C arrays so that assignment works the same as for integers. It makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Don't use manual memory management in modern C++ - please. Use containers and smart pointers and RAII..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I guess I'm just trying to do what I would usually do in C. Probably not the best approach.

Comment: @JohnMeighan Same question would apply to C.

Comment: @John Meighan - C++ is *not* C. And many things are done differently.

Comment: A vector implementation `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would be much less grief to handle.

Comment: @JohnMeighan I use a 1D array and mapping functions to get more dimensions in C as well as C++. You need a larger block of memory, but modern CPUs prefer large continuous runs of data to hopping around chasing pointers. If you got the RAM, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copy assignment operator is bugged (despite your comment it's not a copy constructor). Specifically this

```
std::copy(mat_in.entry, mat_in.entry + (mat_in.nrows * mat_in.mcols), p);
delete[] this -> entry;
```

should be this

```
for(int i=1;i<mat_in.nrows;i++)
    p[i] = p[i-1] + mat_in.mcols;
std::copy(mat_in.entry[0], mat_in.entry[0] + (mat_in.nrows * mat_in.mcols), p[0]);
delete[] this -> entry[0];
delete[] this -> entry;
```

There's a lot of code duplication here, which you should clean up. You should also look into the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) which is a common way of implementing a copy assignment operator.

Comment: OK thanks, can you explain the difference between entry[0] and entry I would have thought they both point to the same place?

Comment: From your constructor you have `entry    = new double*[nrows];
  entry[0] = new double[nrows * mcols];`. Clearly they don't point to the same place.

Comment: `entry[0]` is the same as `*entry` or specifically `*(entry + 0)`.

Comment: Hmm, my code is closer but still not correct. I'll edit to fix it.

Comment: @JohnMeighan I think my code is correct now, but you can probably tell I'm not testing anything.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing the two basic kinds of 2-D array allocation.

In one style, one allocates an array (size nRows) of row pointers, and then allocates an array (size nCols) of elements for each row. Addressing an element is `rows[r][c]`.

In the other style, one allocates an array (size nRows*nCols) of elements for the whole thing. Addressing an element is `elements[(r * nCols) + c]`.